# How to handle alert window in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, while-loop, webautomation

Okay so the problem I am facing is that I want to fill the phone number(lets say) input using Web automation but if it matches on the server I will get an alert window saying "provide different phone no" then I have to accept the alert and provide different phone number

What I am using is that if I get an alert window I will generate a new phone no by subtracting 10 from the previous number, by using **try** and **except**

```
try:
   //fills the number 12340(let's 
   //  say) 

except: #to handle alert
   //generate_new_no() 12330 and 
   //  fills it back
```

Now my question is what If I again gets the alert window(it's possible), how i am going to tackle another alert, definitely I don't want to nest another try and except under the previous except.
What is the optimal solution for this kind of problem.
Basically what I want is to accept alerts and generate and fills new number until there is no alert(means the server accepted the phone number).
Want to use some kind of loop but can't able to decide conditions

Answer (score 0):

Use `try`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')
```

`alert = browser.switch_to.alert`

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit? "timed out waiting for pa creation" with a plus symbol

Comment: That is just the Exception message